# MS ACCESS form's and report's tool bars

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have made an application in MS-Access using forms and reports. But for looking it like a desktop application, i had removed all of the tool bars and navigation options as you can see in the picture. I want to edit this now, how i can be?

[image: This is the picture of my form and Access window that how it look like]

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold Shift during application starting